# how change file name with batch file?

Tags: batch-file

i have 2 file with name : file.txt and file1.txt
Sometimes it is necessary to change the name of these 2 files
for example file1.txt chnage to file.txt And conversely
I'm doing this manually right now
I want to create a batch file that we double-click on it to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "dirname=?:\wherever\your files\reside"
:again
set "tempname=%random%.txt"
if exist "%dirname%\%tempname%" (goto again) else ECHO ren "%dirname%\file1.txt" "%tempname%"
ECHO ren "%dirname%\file.txt" "file1.txt"
ECHO ren "%dirname%\%tempname%" "file.txt"
```

where you assign your directory name to `dirname`.

The code will simply `echo` the commands required. Remove the `echo` keyword after verification to actually perform the name-swap.

Comment: hello. file format is cfg

Comment: set "\\192.168.10.24\db=?:\wherever\your files\reside"
:again
set "tempname=%random%.cfg"
if exist "\\192.168.10.24\db\%tempname%" (goto again) else ECHO ren "\\192.168.10.24\db\dbv.cfg" "%tempname%"
ECHO ren "\\192.168.10.24\db\dbv.cfg" "dbv1.cfg"
ECHO ren "\\192.168.10.24\db\%tempname%" "dbv.cfg"